# Присвоить номер

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет! по нажатию кнопки, я присваиваю переменной значение из таблицы и вывожу на экран, как мне сделать что бы переменная отображалась автоматически на отдельной странице.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $db))  // Присвоение ID
                {
                       $PoleID = $row['ID'];
                       $PoleNumber = $row['Number'];
                       $PoleName = $row['name'];
                       $PoleStatus = $row['Status'];
                       $PoleCod =$row['cod'];
                       $PoleDate = $row['date'];
                       $PoleTime = $row['time'];    
                 if ($PoleCod == 1)  
                    {               
                      $PoleCauseID =  $PoleID + 1;
                      $PoleCauseNumber = $PoleNumber + 1;                         
                    }    
                }   

                 echo " ID = $PoleCauseID, Number = $PoleCauseNumber |";
```

Comment: открытие отдельной страницы может осуществить только сам браузер, со стороны сервера вы не можете этого инициировать. Самым простым способом будет поставить target=_blank у формы в которой находится кнопка (если кнопка типа submit) или открывать отдельное окно явно, кодом на javascript до отправки запроса на сервер

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, нашел решение вот оно

```
<?php
  $delay = isset($_POST["delay"])? $_POST["delay"]: 1;
?>
```

и

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf8">
     <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<?=$delay?>" />
  </head>
```

После разумеется сам код который будет считать цифры